# Finding a match among values occurring previously

Tags: loops, stata

I have the following data set

```
time  person1_person_2   person2_person1   occurrence   cell_count
  1        A_B                B_A               0           1
  2        A_C                C_A               0           2
  3        B_A                A_B               1           3
  4        E_A                A_E               0           4
  5        C_A                A_C               1           5
  6        E_A                A_E               0           6
  7        A_B                B_A               1           7
```

In Stata, I am trying to create the `occurrence` variable. It takes the value of `1` if `person1_person2` occurs in `person2_person1` at an earlier time. For example, if at `time = 4` and `time = 6` `occurrence` takes the value `0` because `E_A` has not occurred in the field `person2_person1`.

I have tried, with no luck:

```
gen occurrence = 0 
local i = cell_count-1
foreach j in `i' {
replace occurrence = 1 if person1_person2 == person2_person1[_n-`j']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, one way to do this is with a loop.

```
clear 
input time  str3 person1_person2   str3 person2_person1   
1        A_B                B_A               
2        A_C                C_A               
3        B_A                A_B               
4        E_A                A_E               
5        C_A                A_C               
6        E_A                A_E               
7        A_B                B_A               
end 

gen occurrence = 0 

qui forval i = 2/`=_N' { 
    local I = `i' - 1 
    count if person2_person1 == person1_person2[`i'] in 1/`I' 
    if r(N) replace occurrence = 1 in `i' 
}
```

`if r(N)` is equivalent to `if r(N) > 0` as `r(N)` being true (non-zero) and being positive are one and the same, as a count can never be negative. `r(N)` is the result left in memory by `count`. See e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0029 and http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033 for tutorials on `count`.

Your code includes the lines

```
local i = cell_count-1
foreach j in `i' {
```

The first will be evaluated as

```
local i = cell_count[1] - 1
```

which comes out as 0, so your loop is just

```
foreach j in 0 {
```

and so is the single line

```
replace occurrence = 1 if person1_person2 == person2_person1[_n]
```

or

```
replace occurrence = 1 if person1_person2 == person2_person1
```

which tests for simultaneous equality. It's not luck you need, but logic!

Comment: In Stack Overflow, a "thank you" is best expressed "accepting" and/or "upvoting" an answer (notice these are two different things). It is by no means mandatory, but it's the idea here. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @NickCox I'm aware; but user1911813 clearly states that his problem is solved. It was meant to be a reminder that he _can_ "accept" instead of posting a "thank-you-only" comment. We are asked not to do so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I am aware of that advice, which is good. My personal take is (still) that "Thank you" beats no reply at all, especially when it includes a signal that the advice was good.

Comment: I agree @NickCox. In this case, something _is_ better than nothing.
I also think there's room for easy improvement in line with Stack Overflow
goals. A "signalling-thank-you" is an improvement over nothing, but an "accept"
is an improvement over a "signalling-thank-you", however impersonal that may be.
I like to be respectfully reminded/informed of opportunities for 
betterment in whatever context. My belief is that, in general, this is good thing. I was aiming for that.

Comment: Absolutely.  We agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, not as straightforward as @Nick Cox's solution, but the general idea is fairly simple: record the time of first occurrences of every value for `p2_p1` and then compare with time of current values of `p1_p2`.

Note there is no explicit loop here which is something I was exploring. It does not necessarily mean it is more efficient.

```
clear all
set more off

clear 
input time  str3 p1_p2   str3 p2_p1   
1        A_B                B_A               
2        A_C                C_A               
3        B_A                A_B               
4        E_A                A_E               
5        C_A                A_C               
6        E_A                A_E               
7        A_B                B_A     
8        P_M                M_P             
9        A_B                B_A
end 

list

tempfile main
save "`main'"

* Create auxiliary data of first occurrences
bysort p2_p1 (time): gen firstflag = (_n == 1) // flag if first occurrence
drop if firstflag == 0 // drop if not first occurrence
drop firstflag p1_p2 // drop unnecessary variables
rename time firsttime // rename accordingly
rename p2_p1 p1_p2 // needed for -merge-

tempfile aux
save "`aux'"

* Merge main data with auxiliary
use "`main'", clear
merge m:1 p1_p2 using "`aux'", keep(master match)

* Compute variable of interest
gen ocurr = (firsttime < time)

* List
drop firsttime _merge
sort time
list
```